# Using an array as a function parameter

Tags: c, arrays, function

I'm writing a program to work out a value from two arrays. I'm having trouble with passing and using arrays in my functions. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h>

const int MAX_STRING = 100;

double mean(double mean_array[]){
    double mean;

    for (int i=0; i<=2000000; i++){
        mean = mean + mean_array[i];
    }

    mean = mean/2000000;

    return mean;

}

double stan_dev_seq(double stan_array[]){

    double mean = mean(stan_array);

    double a;

    for (int i=0; i<=2000000; i++){
        a = a + pow(stan_array[i]-mean, 2);
    }

    a = sqrt(a/2000000);

    return a;
}

int pearson_seq(void){

    double a[2000000];
    double b[2000000];

    double mean_a;
    double mean_b;

    for (int i=0; i<=2000000; i++){
        a[i] = sin(i);
        b[i] = sin(i+2);

    }

    double stan_dev_a = stan_dev_seq(a);
    double stan_dev_b = stan_dev_seq(b);

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    pearson_seq();

return 0;
}
```

And here is the error I get:

```
person_mpi.c: In function ‘stan_dev_seq’:
person_mpi.c:22:16: error: called object ‘mean’ is not a function or function pointer
  double mean = mean(stan_array);
                ^
person_mpi.c:22:9: note: declared here
  double mean = mean(stan_array);
         ^
```

I'm not really sure what is going on, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use different names for your variables and functions

Answer (score 2):

In same scope you can't declare two variables with same name. Either change the variable name `mean` or change the function name `mean`.

The variable name `mean` inside the function `stan_dev_seq` hides the name of function `mean`.

Answer (score 0):

`double mean = mean(stan_array);`

You have a variable called mean, and the compiler is thinking the second `mean` also refers to this variable, rather than to your function. Give them different names.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `mean`, which is *a simple variable* inside your `mean` function.  Just rename it to something different:

```
double N = mean(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

- The name conflicts. Change the name of the local variable `mean` in `stan_dev_seq`.
- You allocate very large array on the stack and it may lead to Segmentation Fault. Consider allocating them on the heap using `malloc` or make them static variable.
- You mustn't access `a[2000000]`, `b[2000000]` or any equivalent because they are out of range.
- The local variable `mean` in the function `mean` isn't initlaized. You should initialize it.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <math.h>

const int MAX_STRING = 100;

double mean(double mean_array[]){
    double mean = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<2000000; i++){
        mean = mean + mean_array[i];
    }

    mean = mean/2000000;

    return mean;

}

double stan_dev_seq(double stan_array[]){

    double mean_data = mean(stan_array);

    double a;

    for (int i=0; i<2000000; i++){
        a = a + pow(stan_array[i]-mean_data, 2);
    }

    a = sqrt(a/2000000);

    return a;
}

int pearson_seq(void){

    static double a[2000000];
    static double b[2000000];

    double mean_a;
    double mean_b;

    for (int i=0; i<2000000; i++){
        a[i] = sin(i);
        b[i] = sin(i+2);

    }

    double stan_dev_a = stan_dev_seq(a);
    double stan_dev_b = stan_dev_seq(b);

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    pearson_seq();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the naming. Variable mean and function mean should have different naming.
and initialize the mean variable.
This should work (BTW I reduced the total number cause it caused SOF on my machine)

```
double calc_mean(double mean_array[]){
    double mean=0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++){
        mean = mean + mean_array[i];
    }

    mean = mean / 2000;

    return mean;

}

double stan_dev_seq(double stan_array[]){

    double mean = calc_mean(stan_array);

    double a=0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++){
        a = a + pow(stan_array[i] - mean, 2);
    }

    a = sqrt(a / 2000);

    return a;
}

int pearson_seq(){

    double a[2000];
    double b[2000];

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++){
        a[i] = sin(float(i));
        b[i] = sin(float(i + 2));

    }

    double stan_dev_a = stan_dev_seq(a);
    double stan_dev_b = stan_dev_seq(b);

    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    pearson_seq();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not access out of range (`a[2000]`, `b[2000]`, etc.)!